# How can I store a variable length array in a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I want to store a variable length array in a struct, and I use a pointer for this purpose. However, if I retrieve the stored array, I get the wrong values back. In the example below, I get the output "1 0", while you would expect the output "1 2".

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Flexibility {
    int *flex;
} Flexibility;

Flexibility calculateFlexibility()
{
    int a[2];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;

    Flexibility f;
    f.flex = a;
    return f;
}


void main()
{
    Flexibility f;
    f = calculateFlexibility();

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%i ", *(f.flex + i));
    }

}
```

Comment: `a` gets out of scope when you return from `calculateFlexibility`, thus `f->flex` points to an array that doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're creating temporary variable `a` in function `calculateFlexibility`, then you store pointer to `f.flex` variable, but after function is ended - `a` is gone from memory, so your `f.flex` pointer is now pointing to nowhere

if you want to have really variable length, you should do something like this:

```
Flexibility calculateFlexibility()
{
    Flexibility f;
    f.flex = (int*)malloc(....);
    return f;
}
```

and at the end of program:

```
free(f.flex);
```

for proper arguments of malloc I suggest you to read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc